# How should I handle push notifications with an app that's distributed through multiple channels?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate

We have developed an iOS app that makes use of push notifications.

Our client wants to distribute the app through their own MDM server. This means they'll compile and sign the app themselves and also have the appropriate APNS certificate, which we include in our server-side application. So far, so good.

Now, the client also wants to distribute the app to other devices that aren't connected to the MDM server. This would mean a different (AdHoc, App Store, ...) distribution channel with a different certificate chain.

How should we handle this on our server side where we send the push notifications to the APNS?

Can we just send every push notification twice, once with each certificate? Do we need to determine which app installation requires which device (depending on the distribution channel)?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically dependent on the way you distribute the app. When distributing if the application identifier is the same it will refer to same app. If it different only it will install multiple times. Means if you have the same app id in both cases its enough to send one notification so that no matter how you distribute it will send the notification. In case if you have changed the app ids yes you have to send that multiple times. Another thing you may do is to change the app id slightly and introduce a wildcard for app id. Which is also fine to send one notification.